# xml Hibernate mapping, many to one with composite ids and different column names

Tags: mysql, xml, hibernate, one-to-many

I am a beginner in hibernate. Basically I want to make UserId1 and UserId2 foreign keys of UserId. I Know I need to use many to one and one to many, but I can't seem to understand how to use them because my columns have different names. Any help is appreciated!
This is my hibernate.hbm.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="objects.UserProfile" table="userProfiles">
        <id name="UserId" column="UserProfileId">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

        <set name="userTracks" table="userTrack" 
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="UserProfileId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="objects.UserTrack" />
        </set>
    </class>
    <class name="objects.UserTrack" table="userTrack">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="UserId1" column="UserProfileId1" type="integer" />      
            <key-property name="UserId2" column="UserProfileId2" type="integer" />           
        </composite-id>   
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So basically both ids in my track class should point to the id in the profile class

my userTrack class:

```
public class UserTrack implements Serializable {

    private int UserProfileId1;
    private int UserProfileId2;


    public int getUserProfileId1() {
        return UserProfileId1;
    }
    public void setUserProfileId1(int userProfiletId1) {
        UserProfiletId1 = userProfileId1;
    }
    public int getUserProfileId2() {
        return UserProfileId2;
    }
    public void setUserProfileId2(int userProfileId2) {
        UserProfileId2 = userProfileId2;
    }

}
```

My profile class:

```
public class UserProfile {

    private int UserProfileId;

    public int getUserProfileId() {
        return UserProfileObjectId;
    }

    public void setUserProfileId(int userProfileId) {
        UserProfileId = userProfileId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mappings should be as follows.

Since there is a **One to Many relation** between `UserProfile` and `UserTrack`,
you can use a `Set<UserTracks> userTracks` in `UserProfile` to keep track of the `UserTrack`s for each `UserProfile`

For **UserProfile** Class

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="objects.UserProfile" table="userProfiles">
        <id name="userProfileId" column="UserProfileId">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

        <!-- other property definitions should come here -->

        <set name="userTracks" table="userTrack" 
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="UserProfileId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="objects.UserTrack" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

For **UserTrack** class

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="objects.UserTrack" table="userTrack">
        <id name="userId" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="userTrackName" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="userProfile" class="objects.UserProfile" fetch="select">
            <column name="UserProfileId" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>        

        <!-- other property definitions should come here -->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

These two xml config files can be integrated to the main `hibernate.cfg.cml` file as follows.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">xxxxxxxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">xxxxxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">xxxxxx</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>

    <mapping resource="path to this file/UserProfile.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="path to this file/UserTrack.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Hope this helps.
More info [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/)

**EDIT : I think Your Entity Classes should be like something similar to the following.**

```
public class UserTrack implements Serializable {
// consider this as the primary key for UserTrack or feel free to change.
    private String userTrackName; 

//    private int UserProfileId1;
//    private int UserProfileId2;

// other attributes related to UserTrack 

}
```

**And**

```
public class UserProfile {

    // you could keep track of the UserTracks that belongs to a 
    //particular UserProfile in the Set.
    // Now a UserProfile can belong to many UserTracks. Not just 2.
    private Set<UserTrack> userTracks = new HashSet<>();

    private int UserProfileId;

    public int getUserProfileId() {
        return UserProfileObjectId;
    }

    public void setUserProfileId(int userProfileId) {
        UserProfileId = userProfileId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but for the user track class, I want composite id. I have two columns in that class userid1 and userid2 that need to reference userid in profile class. how can I do that?

Comment: @amoh: You should keep a Set<UserTracks> userTracks inside UserProfile  class. So you could store many UserTracks as you want.

Could you please add the java code of your entity classes?

Comment: @amoh: I have changed the Entity classes according to my understanding. Please check.

Comment: After doing this I had a problem with duplicate entries. I have restructured my schema and asked a new question if you can help!

Comment: Thanks! this is the link! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980277/many-to-many-xml